# How can call UIViewController to SwiftUI View

Tags: swiftui

I am try to learn SwiftUI . Try to implement SwiftUI code . I am not clear . please anyone help me.

1) Any view controller to other view Controller . it is no problem .

let vc = viewController.init(nibName: "VCNibName", bundle: nil)
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

or

let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCIdentifier") 
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)

2) Any view controller to SwiftUI view .
how can push SwiftUIView to navigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIHostingController` to wrap your View

```
let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: MySwiftUIView())
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(hostingController, animated: true)
```